# How to transform a list of dictionary into a table

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

How to transform a list of dictionary into a table.

Here is the table:

```
[{'wow': 1,
  'item': 1,
  'money': 1},
 {'best': 1,
  'sock': 1,
  'saved': 1,
  'found': 1},
 {'cry': 1,
  'shock': 1,
  'sound': 1}]
```

Desired ouput:

| words | n |
| --- | --- |
| wow | 1 |
| item | 1 |
| ... | ... |

I have tried

```
pd.DataFrame(x , columns=['Words', 'n'])
```

However, the output that I receive is just an index with empty columns.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas melt

```
x = [{'wow': 1,
  'item': 1,
  'money': 1},
 {'best': 1,
  'sock': 1,
  'saved': 1,
  'found': 1},
 {'cry': 1,
  'shock': 1,
  'sound': 1}]

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df = df.melt().dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = ['words', 'n']
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.columns`

An example which you can refer to:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(someInput)
headers = ["Words", "n"]
df.columns = headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaining items of these dictionaries to build may meet your requirements:

```
>>> x = [{'wow': 1,
...   'item': 1,
...   'money': 1},
...  {'best': 1,
...   'sock': 1,
...   'saved': 1,
...   'found': 1},
...  {'cry': 1,
...   'shock': 1,
...   'sound': 1}]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in x), columns=['words', 'n'])
   words  n
0    wow  1
1   item  1
2  money  1
3   best  1
4   sock  1
5  saved  1
6  found  1
7    cry  1
8  shock  1
9  sound  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help

```
  tbl = [{'wow': 1, 'item': 1, 'money': 1}, {'best': 1, 'sock': 1, 'saved': 1, 'found': 1}, {'cry': 1, 'shock': 1, 'sound': 1}] 
  dicts = {}
  for d in tbl:
    dicts.update(d)

  df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(word=list(dicts.keys()), n=list(dicts.values())))
```